# Accessing value of parent scope within directive controller using TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a directive.

```
export class SigninFormDirective implements angular.IDirective {

        // configure directive
        restrict: string =  'AE';
        templateUrl: string = "/public/app/signin/views/directiveTemplates/signinForm.html";
        scope: Object = { formData: "=" };
        controller: Function = SigninDirectiveCtrl;
        controllerAs: string = "form";
        bindToController: boolean = true;

        constructor($http: angular.IHttpService, $q: angular.IQService) {                        

        }        

        static SignupFormFactory(): angular.IDirectiveFactory {

            const directive = ($http: angular.IHttpService, $q: angular.IQService) => {
                return new SigninFormDirective($http, $q);
            };
            directive.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
            return directive;            
        }


    }
```

I want to access my `formData` variable in the directive controller. The `formData` variable is from its parent controller.

```
 // define main controller`
    export class SigninCtrl implements interfaces.ISigninCtrl {

        formData: Object[];
        // define IID on MainController
        static IID = "SigninCtrl";

        // define controller
        constructor(public $state : angular.ui.IState) {
            this.init();            
        }

        private init = () => {
            this.formData = [];
        }



    }
```

In my directive controller, I have a method where I'm trying to access formData:

```
 public submitForm($event: angular.IAngularEvent, email: string, password: string) {            
        var userService = this.userService;
        var utilityService = this.utilityService;            

        // form was submitted
        this.formWasSubmitted();

        if(typeof password === undefined) {
            return;
        } else {                               

            var deferred = this.$q.defer();
            userService.signin(email, password)
            .then(dataObject => {                    
                if(dataObject.data.status.short === "NOTACTIVATED") {                        
                    this.formData.push(dataObject);                        
                    deferred.resolve(dataObject);
                }                                               
            }, error => {
              deferred.reject(error);  
            })                
        }

    }
```

I am using `controllerAs` - how do I access `formData` inside the directive controller? I set up the two way bind, but I'm not sure how to get at it in the controller, using `controllerAs`. Should I use `$scope`? Or can I get by without it? Right now my error is this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out. I had it somewhat right.

You can access the `formData` variable passed to the directive from its parent controller, or any variable passed to your TypeScript Directive controller, simply by using `this`.

ie:

```
this.formData
```

Just be sure to reference your variable in your class, as always.

```
class MyDirectiveCtrl {
    myVar: type;
}
```

If you decide to use `$scope`, you can access the variable by doing

```
$scope.(controllerAlias).myVar
```

But that would be silly, so just use `this`.

My error was coming from a `console.log` I was using that I forgot about. `this.formData.push` worked fine after that.